# Cross-platform encrypted storage

Tags: ios, mobile, windows-phone

I'm creating app that can store some private data (text and images). Amound of data is like 50 documents with 15 text fields each, and about 3-5 attached images.

- Is it better to store data in database (SQLite e.g.) or in textfiles (as binary data)?
- How to encrypt/decrypt images fast? Now I'm developing Windows Phone app, and AES encryption of image is way too long.

Comment: What does "AES encryption of image is way too long" mean? Too slow? Basically use AES128 if you want security. There is always a cost for security.

Comment: Yes, too slow. No matter what key length I'm using: 128 or 256.
Encryption for 10kb data takes about 10sec.

Comment: How are you doing the encryption, 10sec for 10KB, something is wrong.

Comment: Using Apple CommonCrypto, AES-128, iPad3 I got cryptData time: 0.021 ms/KB on a file of length 710KB. That is about 40,000 times faster than your times.

Comment: Where are you doing the timing, iPhone or WinPhone? If WinPhone try in that forum.

Comment: That's strange. I was trying to execute that example on WP8 emulator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.100).aspx
I gave it a string with 10k characters

Comment: The iOS simulators are not emulators, they compile the instruction set of the computer for running in the simulator. I get even faster times in the iOS simulator on my Mac.

Comment: Well, I will inpect my code, maybe I've maesured time in a wrong way, and get back there.

Comment: @Zaph you were right, I measured time in a wrong way. Encryption of 1mb data takes about 1 second.